# Filter dataframe by value NOT present in column of other dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Banging my head a little with this one, and I suspect the answer is very simple. Given two dataframes, I want to filter the first where values in one column are not present in a column of another dataframe.

I would like to do this without resorting to full-blown Spark SQL, so just using DataFrame.filter, or Column.contains or the "isin" keyword, or one of the join methods.

```
val df1 = Seq(("Hampstead", "London"), 
              ("Spui", "Amsterdam"), 
              ("Chittagong", "Chennai")).toDF("location", "city")
val df2 = Seq(("London"),("Amsterdam"), ("New York")).toDF("cities")

val res = df1.filter(df2("cities").contains("city") === false)
// doesn't work, nor do the 20 other variants I have tried
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: try below code, it will work :-

 val df3 = Seq(("Hampstead", "London"), 
              ("Spui", "Amsterdam"), 
              ("Chittagong", "Chennai")).toDF("location", "city")
         val df4 = Seq(("London"),("Amsterdam"), ("New York")).toDF("cities")
         
         df3.where(df3("city").isInCollection(df4.map(_.getString(0)).collect())).show()

Answer (score 14):

I've discovered that I can solve this using a simpler method - it seems that an antijoin is possible as a parameter to the join method, but the Spark Scaladoc does not describe it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq(("Hampstead", "London"), 
              ("Spui", "Amsterdam"), 
              ("Chittagong", "Chennai")).toDF("location", "city")
val df2 = Seq(("London"),("Amsterdam"), ("New York")).toDF("cities")

df1.join(df2, df1("city") === df2("cities"), "leftanti").show
```

Results in:

```
+----------+-------+ 
|  location|   city| 
+----------+-------+ 
|Chittagong|Chennai| 
+----------+-------+
```

P.S. thanks for the pointer to the duplicate - duly marked as such

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to filter a `DataFrame` using another, you should use `join` (or any of its variants). If what you need is to filter it using a `List` or any data structure that fits in your master and workers you could broadcast it, then reference it inside the `filter` or `where` method.

For instance I would do something like:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq(("Hampstead", "London"), 
              ("Spui", "Amsterdam"), 
              ("Chittagong", "Chennai")).toDF("location", "city")
val df2 = Seq(("London"),("Amsterdam"), ("New York")).toDF("cities")

df2.join(df1, joinExprs=df1("city") === df2("cities"), joinType="full_outer")
   .select("city", "cities")
   .where(isnull($"cities"))
   .drop("cities").show()
```

Comment: Ok, but which join would achieve the result I want? I believe I should be looking at an anti-join, but this is not an option according to the Scaladoc. Also, I agree that I can use filter on a List (... something like df.filter(($"col" isin <list>) === false), but then how can I turn the Column I want to reference into a List?