# Left Anti join in Spark dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, anti-join

I have two dataframes, and I would like to retrieve only the information of one of the dataframes, which is not found in the inner join, see the picture:

[image: Full outer join]

I have tried several ways: Inner join and filtering the rows that return at least one null, all the types of joins described on the docs for **Spark 1.6** but failed to do obtain the results from just one join.

Can anybody help?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're  right, corrected name

Comment: @user8371915  Not working in Spark 1.6

Comment: I edited duplicate targets to include [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40245393/8371915) which doesn't depend on `leftanti` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called right excluding join and you can do like below

```
df1.join(df2,df1("column1")===df2("column2"),"right_outer").filter("column1 is null").show
```